# what is buzzword for a too many cups of coffee

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, slang

Like the term Boozer is for a drunk, what is the buzzword used for a person who has too many cups of coffee or an overload of caffeine? General used amongst the digital generation sipping away in 
Coffee shops.

Answer (score 1):

[From Wiktionary:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/overcaffeinated)

> **overcaffeinated**, having ingested too much caffeine, especially in the form of coffee

I don’t think it’s a buzzword, though. The word is rarely used: only 59 hits in the iWeb corpus.

Other alternatives:

1. A coffeeholic
2. A coffee-addict
3. A coffee-junkie

Answer (score 0):

"Caffeine addicts". Or possibly "caffeine zombies". There isn't really any specific term, but anything you make up will be understood. Maybe "coffee-holic"?

Answer (score -1):

[caffeineaholic](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=caffeineaholic) seems to fit best to your intensions.